# write variable into specific line with sed command

Tags: sed

```
echo -n "##### STATIONS? #######"
read station
text="stab_site "
```

I need to write echo `$text$station` into the 27th line of text file. I used below command but it didn't work,

```
sed -i "27i\$text$station" text.data
```

it produce; `$textankr ista` "text" variable cannot be passed within sed function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your shell is interpreting `\$` to mean a literal (escaped) dollar sign. Try

```
sed -i "27i\\$text$station" text.data
```

or using a mix of single- and double-quotes

```
sed -i '27i\'"$text$station" text.data
```

or with a literal newline

```
sed -i "27i\
$text$station" text.data
```

(which is more POSIXly correct, I think).

Comment: how can I give one space after the beginning of the written line?

Comment: @deepblue_86 where exactly? You should be able to add a literal space anywhere in the replacement text e.g. ` $text$station` or `$text $station` or `$text$station `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem can be a empty output file.
Example:
    #!/bin/bash

```
CAMINHO='/etc/scripts/dropbox.log'

RESULTADO=`date +%d/%m/%Y | tr '\n' ' '; dropbox status;`

sed -i "1i\
$RESULTADO" /etc/scripts/dropbox.log
```

This script cant write to a empty file dropbox.log.

Write some text on file and execute script again.

Comment: The problem was solved with the other answer; why would it be caused by an empty output file?